# Stack Overflow post character limit - Two different validation counts

Tags: bug, editor, character-limit

**EDIT**
The issue is two different character counts to validate a post.

1. On textarea blur (Correct count)
2. On submit (Incorrect count by 501 chars more)

Possible factor: a hidden snippet?

---

I just met the 30,000 character limit for my post (an edit of my posted answer) for the first time.

The issue is not the limit itself, but the strange issue I encountered, which *may* be a bug.

While editing, on blur of the edit textarea, a redish alert popped, telling I I was over limit. It also displayed how many characters I had (30,160 by memory), which is good.

So I shortened my answer a bit...

Then, bluring again, it finally seemed correct since the alert wasn't showing anymore.

But on "Save edit" click, the alert came back with a character count obviously false by 501 characters more. And yes, I used a [character counter](http://www.lettercount.com/) to be sure.

Now, that is quite hard to submit a *reproducible demo* here, I have no idea how.

If that can be usefull, [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46105240/2159528) where it occured. I finally had to remove the *snippet* to complete my answer... Even if it's always strongly suggested to use it instead of a *CodePen*.

Comment: So it was the Stack Snippet that took you slightly over?  Could you post what that snippet looked like above (just as a code block, nothing executable) so that we could also poke at it?

Comment: The [revision #1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46105240/1) should be good to look at the snippet.

Comment: I wonder if there are 2 different checks that take place here. The first check simply validates content length when you leave the text area to show the warning. Secondly, with you having a stack snippet, when you submit, server side may do something with the snippeted code (that adds characters) and then run an additional content length check giving you the anomaly. Just thinking out loud.

Comment: There is no reason to include both the code (as plain text) *and* the Stack Snippet. No wonder you went over the character limit: you posted *twice as much* as you needed to!

Comment: @CodyGray: I wanted the OP to focus on the code... The snippet display was quite too long. CSS and HTML was not relevant, but needed for the snippet.

Comment: @CodyGray: Anyway, that is not the reason of the issue I'm reporting. Like Tanner says, I noticed two different char counts.

Comment: To reproduce, I'd start with using http://www.lipsum.com/ to generate a specific number of bytes and then add a snippet. I made an answer someone can attempt to blow up below.